# Syntax error in custom function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, parameters

I'm getting a **syntax error** in the first line of the following code. I'm using [array function parameters as shown in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). After removing the brackets **from String()** the error disappears, but I need an array of strings.
My code so far:

```
Private Function Contains(name As String, names As String()) As Boolean
Contains = False

Dim Index As Integer
For Index = 0 To names.GetUpperBound(0)
    If names(Index) = name Then
        Contains = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: You code is not exactly the same as the code in the MSDN article.

Comment: no exactly same, but in MSDN they use Private Sub ShowNumbers(**numbers As Integer()**)
and in my code it is **names As String()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brackets for the array should go after the variable name, not after the type:

```
names() as String
```

instead of

```
names as String()
```

BTW: `name` and `names` aren't good variable names to use! It's best to be a little more descirptive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Private Function Contains(name As String, names() As String) As Boolean
```

or

```
Private Function Contains(name As String, ByRef names() As String) As Boolean
```

Depending on what you need.